# jQuery onChange: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I'm trying out a javascript in my rails with jQuery setup, but I'm getting an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string"

```
$(document).ready({
  $('#pitch_name').on('change',function() {
    $('#edit_pitch_name').remove();
  });
});
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: missing `function()` i.e. `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Comment: Yep, that's it! I was completely blind-sided... Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written a wrong syntax of `document.ready` missing of `function()`, you should use below code::

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Your code
});
```

Official documentation:: [Link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#pitch_name').on('change',function() {
    $('#edit_pitch_name').remove();
  });
});
```